# Why is $\dim(V/\bigcap_{i=1}^n\ker(f_i))\leq n$ for linear functionals $f_i$?

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm confused by a paragraph in my notes.

Suppose $V$ is a vector space (possibly infinite dimensional), and $f_1,\dots,f_n$ are linearly independent functionals in the dual space $V'$. Let $K=\bigcap_{i=1}^n\ker(f_i)$, a subspace of $V$, and consider the quotient $V/K$. Since the codimension of $\ker(f_i)$ is at most one, $V/K$ is finite dimensional and $\dim(V/K)\leq n$.

Since $V/\ker(f_i)\cong\operatorname{im}(f_i)=F$, I get that the codimension of each functional is $1$. But how can you deduce $V/K$ is finite dimensional of dimension at most $n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll denote the base field by $F$ like you. Consider the linear map 
$$
T:V\longrightarrow F^n\qquad v\longmapsto (f_1(v),\ldots,f_n(v)).
$$
Then $K:=\ker T=\ker f_1\cap \ldots\cap \ker f_n$. So $T$ factors into an injective linear map
$$
\overline{T}:V/K\longrightarrow F^n.
$$
Therefore $\dim V/K=\mbox{rank } \overline{T}\leq n$.

Remark: actually, now I see you assume your $n$ linear functionals to be linearly independent, the range of $T$ and $\overline{T}$ must be the whole of $F^n$ and the dimension of $V/K$ is $n$. Indeed, assume that the range of $T$ has dimension less than $n$. Then it is contained in a hyperplane $H$, i.e. the nullspace of a linear functional $H=\{w\in F^n\,;\,a_1w_1+\ldots+a_nw_n=0 \}$, where at least one $a_j$ is nonzero. Hence $a_1f_1+\ldots+ a_nf_n=0$, contradicting the linear independence of the $f_j$'s.

Comment: could you tell me some good reference for studying codimension and its properties?